# Magento getLoadedProductCollection vs getProductCollection (Configurable Swatches issue)

Tags: php, magento

Right now I have a custom category page that loops through all of the categories child categories, and their grandchild categories and echoes out all of their products in different sections on the page.

The top of the list.phtml file calls

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Which allows configurable swatches to work on regular category pages.

I'm loading the subcategories by doing this...

```
$childCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($childId);
```

and

```
$grandChildCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($grandChildId);
```

Which allows me to create a grid of their products, however it seems I have to load their products this way...

```
$_gcProductCollection = $grandChildCategory->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Which leaves all the json data for the configurable swatches js empty. Replacing each of them with this...

```
$_gcProductCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

works and pulls the data for the swatches, however then I end up with EVERY product from each category in every single section, with the swatches only working on the top one.

Is there a way to filter getLoadedProductCollection, or use getProductCollection with enough data to where the swatches script works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

In the configurableswatches/catalog/media/js.phtml file the full product was not being loaded. Loading the full product in this file first let all the json data show up.